# Href link is not working in magento

Tags: magento, hyperlink

can anybody help me that i created a static code in magento header.phtml file for a simple link with href tag but href tag is not working.
This is my code

```
<a href-"abc.php">Cart</a>
```

Comment: where is your abc.php file is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `-` sign should be an equals sign

This is wrong

```
<a href-"abc.php">Cart</a>
```

This is right

```
<a href="abc.php">Cart</a>
```